# How do I properly set bash profile on Mac terminal

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I am using Mac and I don't like my current terminal setting because it shows all path to current directory, which is unnecessarily long...

For example,

```
jaekwangkim@jaekwangkim:~/codes/github/grainboundary/Cplusplus$
```

while I don't need all absolute path `~/codes/github/grainboundary/`

how do I make it shorter in bash_profile?

My current PS1 is as follows

```
PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\.       [\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
```

Comment: This question would be better suited for Unix & Linux, but there's already one there: [How do I shorten the current directory path shown on terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381113/117037)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep just the following portion
`PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h: "` then it will show only the following `jaekwangkim@jaekwangkim:`

To have some fun, [visit this link](http://bashrcgenerator.com/)